# How to integrate AWS Cognito for only Developer authenticated developers?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, openid-connect, amazon-cognito

We have done integration of AWS for Unauthenticated access but when we trying for Authenticated access then we getting error of **InvalidParameterException: Please provide a valid public provider.**

we using following steps for AWS integration into application:

```
DeveloperAuthenticationProvider developerProvider = new DeveloperAuthenticationProvider(
                    AppConstants.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID, AppConstants.IdentityPoolId, Regions.EU_WEST_1
            );
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    getActivity(),
                    developerProvider,
                    Regions.EU_WEST_1); 

//set Logings for Authenticated Access
HashMap<String, String> loginsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
           loginsMap.put(developerProvider.getProviderName(), Token);
            credentialsProvider.setLogins(loginsMap);
            credentialsProvider.refresh();
```

We have done with DeveloperAuthenticationProvider class, which extends AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider; where we provide developer provider name(developerProvider.getProviderName()) and Token is as a OpenID token.

But I getting below errors:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.InvalidParameterException: Please provide a valid public provider
```

and sometimes I getting errors of:
**Identity ID is forbidden**.
I couldn't understand causes of these errors. I referred following URLs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/, https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en.

Please suggest me how can I solve out these errors and give some updated references where I can understand causes of these errors.

Comment: Can you please share the code in your developer provider where you are assigning the token? From the error you are describing it seems you are assigning this to the logins map, not the token field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hurreyyy, I resolved issue of Developer Authentication for AWS Cognito Service. Its easy to understand but quite hard to implement.

Here is solution :

`CognitoSyncClientManager.init(this, cognitoParams);
 CognitoSyncClientManager.credentialsProvider.clearCredentials();
 CognitoSyncClientManager.addLogins(AppConstants.DEVELOPER_PROVIDER, strToken);` and you can get CognitoSyncClientManager from [CognitoSyncDemo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo). 
Thanks to all

Comment: Where is AppConstants? What is it?

Comment: I guess AppConstants is his custom class where DEVELOPER_PROVIDER could be `login.companyname.appname` i.e. it is the  Developer provider name you have provided in the cognito setup.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are setting the token in the logins map, instead of the token field of your developer provider as noted in the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/#associate-developer-provider). You may also want to refer to our [end-to-end example](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) available on GitHub which includes example code for both iOS and Android.

Comment: I refered that documents. I pass developer provider name and token as login params for CognitoSyncClientManager. But it returns same error which i mentioned in above comments.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the value you're returning from `developerProvider.getProviderName()` is the same value that you have registered in the Amazon Cognito console as described in the steps under the [*Associate Developer Provider* section of the Developer Authenticated Identities topic in the Amazon Cognito Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/#associate-developer-provider).

Comment: Scott Willeke, Thanks for your reply.Yes developer.getProviderName is correct. and I also tested token on [http://jwt.io/]. It giving me right information but with Invalid Signature.

Comment: it returns error: `Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.InvalidParameterException: Please provide a valid public provider (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: daca4cc0-2ae0-11e5-889e-39d5cbca50d0)`